# How can I know a file exists or not?

Tags: java, android, android-file, file-exists

I wrote this code on android to learn whether a .txt file exists or not.

```
    File file_a =new File("a.txt");

 InputStream in3 = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.b);
         FileOutputStream out3 = null;


        try {   out3=openFileOutput("a.txt",Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
         byte[] buff3 = new byte[1024];
         int read3 = 0; 

         try {
            while ((read3 = in3.read(buff3)) > 0) {
               out3.write(buff3, 0, read3);
            }
         } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        } finally {
              try {
                in3.close();
                out3.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

         }

    boolean a=file_a.exists();
```

It always returns `false`.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Do you have permission to read the location at which the file is stored?

Comment: I doubt that you are allowed to write on the root directory of you android device. The returned value is therefor correct.

Comment: I dont understand? File is exist. I read values in it.But boolean a is false? how is that? file is exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution.I tried the read file if its get the catch block it is not exist. thanks everyone.

```
try {
        FileInputStream deneme=openFileInput("a.txt");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         kopyala();
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: This is wrong. You shouldn't be trying to access the root directory in the first place. Use your app's internal storage, or the SD Card.

Comment: but this is work on my phone? and my phone is not rooted device?

Comment: I'm not saying it won't work. I'm saying it shouldn't be done. And for the record, it won't work across all devices.

Comment: Because you're doing it wrong. Some devices allow access to areas that should be root only. For example, my optimus one lets me access the framebuffer, while my Nexus s doesn't, as the framebuffer should be protected.

Comment: so How can ı create file nad where? give me path but it must be is phone memory

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal

Comment: its same with me? why its true and my is false

Comment: I m doing it true? My code is same with yours? what is the difference

Answer (score 1):

You have not created a file at all. All you have done is instantiate a file handle.

Comment: edit my question I create already but it says no file but it is  exist

Answer (score 1):

You can create `File` if its not exist

using this

```
if(!file.exist()){
file.createNewFile( ); 
}
```

after that when you call `file.exist();` it will return `true`

Answer (score 0):

**It is not always return false.**

`File#exists()` return true if and only if the file or directory denoted by this abstract pathname exists; false otherwise.

You are creating a new file then you should call `File#createNewFile` which return true if it is successfully created otherwise false.

In file is already created then you can check the `File#getAbsolutePath()` to verify the absolute path of file is same or not.

Comment: so how  can i understand the file is exist

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the path to the file as well as the file name.  Assuming the file is on your sd card in the root directory there:

```
File file_a = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/a.txt"); 
boolean a=file_a.exists();
```

If it is in a subdirectory, add the rest of the path:

```
    File file_a = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "yourpath/a.txt");
```

If you have written the file to internal storage, it is somewhere in the "data/data/your.package.name" path, use that.

```
    File file_a = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "date/data/your.package.name/a.txt");
```

Comment: You can remove concatenations by using `new File(String directory, String filename)`